# Graph get emails with PDF attachments and download

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments, microsoft-graph-mail

I have been trying to get this going all day and have gone through most of the questions on here.  Can't  get it to work I know the emails being pulled have PDF attachments but when I run the code I don't get anything being pulled down.  In fact the attachments object often shows up as NULL however HasAttachments returns true and gives me a URL.  Anyone have any ideas ?

```
int i = 0;
var msgs = _graphServiceClient.Users["abc@Turtles.com "].Messages.Request().Filter("(from/emailAddress/address) eq 'noreply@adr.org'").Top(5000).Header("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='text'").GetAsync().Result;
foreach (var message in msgs) //.Where(a => a.Subject.Contains("Defense reminder notifications")))
{

    var mesAtt = _graphServiceClient.Users["abc@Turtles.com"].Messages[message.Id].Request().Expand("Attachments").GetAsync();
    
    if (message.HasAttachments == true && message.Attachments != null) { 
        var fileAttachment = message.Attachments.OfType<FileAttachment>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.ContentId == "application/pdf");

    int b = 0;
    if (fileAttachment != null)
    {
        var base64 = fileAttachment.ContentBytes;
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\TMP\" + b + "file.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
        System.IO.BinaryWriter writer =
        new BinaryWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(base64, 0, base64.Length);
        writer.Close();
     }
     b++;
}
```

Comment: is the file attached by value in Outlook? do you see the file content in Outlook or it is just a link to a file put on one drive or any other web storage?

Comment: The is attached is in outlook, was received as a PDF attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering how I finally ended up getting this to work here it is:
Also contrary to Greg's comment the only way I got this to pull back more than 10 records is calling Top()

```
var messages = _graphServiceClient.Users["ab2@123.com"].Messages.Request().Top(1000).Filter("(hasAttachments eq true) and ((from/emailAddress/address) eq 'noreply@adr.org')").Expand("attachments").GetAsync().Result;
int i = 0;
if (messages.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Message message in messages)
    {
       var fileAttachment = message.Attachments.OfType<FileAttachment>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.Contains(".pdf"));
       if (fileAttachment != null)
       {
           var base64 = fileAttachment.ContentBytes;
           System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\TMP\" + i + "file.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
           System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
           writer.Write(base64, 0, base64.Length);
           writer.Close();
           i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (message.HasAttachments == true && message.Attachments != null) { 
    var fileAttachment = message.Attachments.OfType<FileAttachment>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.ContentId == "application/pdf");
```

This doesn't look correct to me you should never have application/pdf in the contentId this is supposed to be a unique value and is usually a Guid. I would suggest you try to expand one message with attachments first in the Graph Explorer and take a look at the result. The only place you may see application/pdf is in the contentType and/or mediaContentType but that is also not guaranteed and maybe an application/octet-stream depending on the original encoder.  eg this is one example

```html
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('-8cf15854b555')/messages(attachments,attachments())/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAB1EEf9GOowTZ1AsUKLrCDQAAejSsO4\"",
    "id": "ASAAA=",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "application/pdf",
            "id": "AAMkADczNDE4YWEwLTdlZmItNDIzZC04MDViLTYyYjI2YmRhYzI2ZABGAAAAAAC_HN09lgYnSJDz3kt9375JBwB1EEf9GOowTZ1AsUKLrCDQAAAAAAEMAAB1EEf9GOowTZ1AsUKLrCDQAAek6VdSAAABEgAQAKqtypyRZE1Jg0YRo9yWihE=",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-03-27T03:17:31Z",
            "name": "62104645031_000347650792_P_20230327.pdf",
            "contentType": "application/pdf",
            "size": 166611,
            "isInline": false,
            "contentId": "6A672F3051E9254CB0E45C863C128A01@apcprd04.prod.outlook.com",
            "contentLocation": null,
            "contentBytes":""
        }
}
```

The most generic/reliable method would be just to check for a .pdf extension in the name.

Also don't do

```
Top(5000)
```

The Graph will limit you to 1000 items in a page, that would possible confuse another developer if you want to process that number of items you will need to page the results.